# How to register a servlet in Ktor?

Tags: servlets, ktor

I'm looking for a way to register a javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet in ktor, but can't find any.

Do I need to install a feature? Register it in Routing? Can I enable scanning of `@WebServlet` annotations?

Example servlet:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/foo")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: ktor is not a servlet container however you can deploy both ktor and your servlets into the same servlet container such as jetty or tomcat

Comment: @serg But ktor embeeds Netty, Tomcat, etc. so I thought I could register a servlet while configuring the running container.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is currently not supported by design. See my [Feature Request](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/1741) and corresponding [PR](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/pull/1773) to add support for it.